# Query: How to find erroneous components against a required items list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query in MS SQL 2008 that compares a list of items and their components against a list of paired item-required-component to ensure that no item contains a component it shouldn't. I'm looking for an elegant solution.

My tables are as follows:

Required components:

```
Rayon Shirt - Blue Fabric - Bone Buttons. 
Cotton Shirt - Red Fabric - Plastic buttons
```

Data:

```
Model-Component
DKNY-Rayon
DKNY-Blue
DKNY-Bone
Nike-Cotton
Nike-Red
Nike-Bone
```

So my task is to find out any model that has [Rayon and (not blue fabric or not bone buttons)] or [cotton and (not red fabric or not plastic buttons)]. This is very simplified, as my data table is 37,000 records long.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: can you give table schema with sample data populated?

Comment: How do you know if it is the fabric or the buttons that are blue?

Comment: I thought I did just above. Forgive me as I'm new at this. first table is 3 columns, and I've included 2 sample rows. Second table is 2 columns, and 6 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited the first table to make it more clear. The two components are not the same, so there would not be any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want models where the components do not match any of the patterns.  The following gets a list of all the models and matching requirements, along with the number that match:

```
select d.model, r.requiredid, count(distinct d.component) as nummatches
from data d left join
     required r
     on d.component = r.component1 or
        d.component = r.component2 or
        d.component = r.component3
group by d.model, r.requiredid;
```

What you want from this is the number of models that do not have 3 matches.  Let's do this with `not in`:

```
select distinct d.model
from data d
where d.model not in (select d.model
                      from data d left join
                           required r
                           on d.component = r.component1 or
                              d.component = r.component2 or
                              d.component = r.component3
                      group by d.model, r.requiredid
                      having count(distinct d.component) = 3
                     );
```